# android:textDirection="locale" for api 15

Tags: android, textview, locale

i try to make my text aligned according to my android locale.

In my TextView I have tried:

`android:textDirection="locale"`

but that's for API 17 and above.

I have tried:

```
android:gravity=start
```

but my text is aligned according to the text locale and not the device locale.

how can i fix this to api 15?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

or

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
android:gravity="start"
```

`layout_gravity` or `gravity` is needed for API < 17

Comment: how can `android:gravity="start"` be exchange so easily with `android:layout_gravity="start` the mean different things.

Comment: i get the same error: `textAlignment is for API 17 and above`

Comment: This is the ide's suggestion because `android:textAlignment` was introduced in API=17 to include  layout_gravity or gravity

Comment: Just read the suggestion when you hover the mouse above the red line

Comment: i have tried both option, no warning. but text is still aligned according to input locale and not device locale.

Comment: What is your min API?

Comment: API 14. I cannot find a published solution

Comment: Are you sure that device locale is different, because some settings in the locale can be overriden

Comment: how can i check for sure? by code you mean?
the settings show the device locale is US english
and I see the right alignment for android api 17 and above

I need the device locale direction to override the text content locale direction

Comment: if the device locale is set to US english and with the above code the text is right aligned then for sure there's a problem with the settings of the device or the settings of your app. Can you post your manifest?